# Font in 'On writing well' (25th anniversary edition) by Zinsser

Tags: font-identification

I recently read the celebrated [*On Writing Well, 25th Anniversary: The Classic Guide to Writing Nonfiction*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060006641) by William Zinsser. The book is fantastic as people recommended, but the book font is also amazing.

[image]

[image]

I tried [myfonts](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) and [identifont.com](http://www.identifont.com/) but in vain. Can anyone tell me which font is used in Zinsser's book? (For your information, the book is published by HarperCollins.)

Comment: If it isn't an actual variant or derivative of Baskerville, it's certainly something very akin to Baskerville. Does the colophon not say anything about it?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet looks very different from Baskerville to me

Comment: @Ryan Many of the actual variants of Baskerville look quite different from Baskerville. If it isn’t one of those, I’d say it’s very likely to be inspired by Baskerville.

Comment: I'd ask the experts at the "WhatTheFont" forum over at myfonts.com, they'll have an answer pretty quickly I'm sure.  http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font used in the book is New Caledonia.

[image]
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/new-caledonia/

Comment: Can you please give some hints how you identified this font?  That could be helpful for other readers which steps are useful to identify fonts by their own.  Thanks and welcome to GD.SE!